# For loop not working

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, loop-device

I'm creating a bash script that among other things, checks a list against another list.
Basicly, I created this for loop to check the file "data.txt" for every item in "names.txt" And all matches should be output to "confirmed.txt" which, when finished, should be shown on screen. But for some reason, the file is always blank, am i missing somthing?

test

```
for code in data.txt 
do
    grep $code names.txt >> confirmed.txt
done
cat confirmed.txt
rm confirmed.txt
```

Comment: If the items in `data.txt` are one-per-line, then you can skip the loop altogether and use `grep -f data.txt names.txt` or `grep -Ff data.txt names.txt` if you want them to be treated as fixed strings rather than basic regular expressions. (There's also no need to redirect the matching lines to a file that you're only going to `cat` once and then delete.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for code in `cat data.txt`
do
    grep $code names.txt >> confirmed.txt
done
cat confirmed.txt
rm confirmed.txt
```

Comment: I'm unsure why this worked and my set didn't, but thank you

Comment: `for code in data.txt`, $code is `data.txt`. Because `for` does not read the file `data.txt`. `data.txt` is just a word/string. \``cat data.txt`\` makes it read the file.